# How to install mod_pagespeed on apache with windows, and from where to download

Tags: apache, mod-pagespeed

I want to download mod_pagespeed module by google on my windows + apache installation.

Any one can show me from where to download and install on apache with windows?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Download here:

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html

Installation documentation here:

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/using_mod.html

Comment: Read the first page for the list of supported platforms. Nobody has precompiled a binary for Windows yet, but you can download the source and modify it to compile in Windows yourself. If you are not comfortable compiling your own software, you will not be installing mod_pagespeed in Windows.

Comment: -1 this will not work on windows with out heavy modification of the mod_pagespeed source

Answer (score 2):

We currently have the mod_pagespeed module compiling and loading into Apache on Windows on a dev machine. However - we first need to fix a few things before it can be used as intended and released to the public.

Once we have it working correctly, we will offer a free download. Keep an eye on http://www.iispeed.com/ - we will announce it over there in a few weeks.

Comment: This module you're offering in your webpage it's only for IIS, not for Apache on Windows.

Comment: Correct, supporting Apache on Windows initially looked like low hanging fruit, but we ended up running into issues that we never got around to resolving, sorry