# mod_pagespeed for Tomcat in windows xp?

Tags: pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

Can I use  mod_pagespeed for Tomcat 7 in **windows xp** ?If yes , can some one provide me with the details on how to do it ? I found a similar question on SO [how to install mod_pagespeed on apache with windows, and from where to downlaod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415984/how-to-install-mod-pagespeed-on-apache-with-windows-and-from-where-to-downlaod) but that was some time back and it turned out at that time that it was not doable easily without changing source code . So I am hoping that something has changed since that post .

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, nobody has ported mod_pagespeed to Tomcat. You would have to edit the source code to do this. Alternatively you could put an Apache HTTPD server in front of Tomcat, but mod_pagespeed on windows is also not directly supported.

Comment: An example configuration for mod_pagespeed set up as a proxy is:

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/experiment#Trying%20out%20mod_pagespeed%20using%20mod_proxy

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing is http://requestreduce.org/ (free) or Aptimize ($$$) but both are IIS plugins so you'll need IIS infront of Tomcat