# mod_pagespeed for Apache 2.4 and Windows Server 2008 r2

Tags: windows, apache, mod-pagespeed

[mod_pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/mod) is stable now but there's no version for Windows. Does anybody compiled the module for Windows successfully?

Thanks!

Comment: Run it on line: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights  then make changes.

Comment: I did tried the online tool. The advantage of mod_pagespeed is that it does the changes for me automatically and it would allow me to simplify my codebase.

Comment: run on apache then copy on production server. mod_pagespeed on IIS imposibre, is the same situation like with SPDY protocol

Comment: You really like to use "dirty" solutions, don't you? Do you realize how much work does it represents on a medium size website?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415984/how-to-install-mod-pagespeed-on-apache-with-windows-and-from-where-to-downlaod

Answer (score 1):

mod_pagespeed does not currently work on Windows. But there is a PageSpeed port to ISS called IISpeed: http://www.iispeed.com/.

Answer (score 0):

We currently have the mod_pagespeed module compiling and loading into Apache on Windows on a dev machine. However - we first need to fix a few things before it can be used as intended and released to the public.

Once we have it working correctly, we will offer a free download. Keep an eye on http://www.iispeed.com/ - we will announce it over there in a few weeks.